# Initial value problem $t\frac{dx}{dt}=x+\sqrt{t^2+x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Another question on ODEs, this time just wondering how I should start with this one.
$$t\frac{dx}{dt}=x+\sqrt{t^2+x^2}, \qquad x(1)=0.$$ It looks like a linear ODE and so after playing around with it I eventually got $$\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{2}{t}x=\frac{dt}{dx}$$ to which I multiplied the integrating factor $$I(t)=t^{-2}=\frac{1}{t^2}.$$ This in turn gave me $$\frac{x}{t^2}=\int{\frac{1}{t^2}t'dt},$$ and then I used integration by parts to get $$\frac{x}{t^2}=\frac{-1}{t}+C.$$ Applying the initial conditions gave me $$x=t(t-1).$$ The answer in the book is however $$x=\frac{1}{2}(t^2-1).$$

Where did I go wrong? What should I do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked whether you (and the book's) answer satisfies the original equation?

Comment: @jamesh625: The book solution is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Hint to guide you through (fill in the details):

Let $x = tv$

We have $x' = v + t v'$, so:

$t\dfrac{dx}{dt}= t(t v' + v) = tv + \sqrt{t^2+t^2 v^2}$

Simplifying, we get:

$v' = \dfrac{\sqrt {v^2+1}}{t} \rightarrow \dfrac{v'}{\sqrt {v^2+1}} = \dfrac{1}{t}$

Upon integrating, we have $v(t) = \sinh (\ln t + c)$, so:

$x(t) = t v = t \sinh (\ln t + c)$.

If we use the initial condition, you get $c = 0$.

Can you finish it off? (You know the expansion for $\sinh x$, use it and you end up with the book answer.

**Update**

Here are the details for:

$$\tag 1 \int \dfrac{dv}{\sqrt {v^2+1}}$$

Let $v = \tan u \rightarrow dv = \sec^2 u ~du$

Note, from the above substitution, we have $u = \tan^{-1} v$ (we need this later).

So, $\sqrt{1 + v^2} = \sqrt{1 + \tan^2 u} = \sec u$

Substituting and simplifying into $(1)$, yields:

$$\tag 2 \int \dfrac{dv}{\sqrt {v^2+1}} = \int \sec u ~du$$

Lets multiply the numerator and denominator of $(2)$ by $(\sec u + \tan u)$, so we have:

$$\tag 3 \int \sec u ~du = \int \sec u \dfrac{\sec u + \tan u}{\sec u + \tan u} ~du = \int \dfrac{\sec^2 u + \sec u \tan u}{\sec u + \tan u} ~du$$

Let $w =  (\sec u + \tan u) \rightarrow dw = (\sec^2 u + \sec u \tan u)~ dw$, so $(3)$ reduces to:

$$\tag 4 \int \dfrac{1}{w}~dw = \ln w + c$$

Substituting $w$ back into $(4)$, yields:

$$\tag 5 \ln(\sec u + \tan u) + c$$

But, recall from the work above, we have, $u = \tan^{-1} v$, so substituting into $(5)$, yields:

$$\tag 6 \ln(\sec(\tan^{-1} v) + \tan(\tan^{-1} v) + c$$

However, from the substitutions we made within $(1)$, we have $\sec(\tan^{-1} v) = \sqrt{1 + v^2}$, so $(6)$ reduces to:

$$\ln(\sqrt{1 + v^2} + v) + c$$

**Update 2**

Now, we have:

$$\ln(\sqrt{1 + v^2} + v) + c = \ln t + c$$

We can make a substitution for the LHS using $\sinh$ or work with it in its current form.

Taking exponential, solving for $v(t)$, substituting in $x(t) = v t$ and using the IC, we arrive at:

$$x(t) = \dfrac{1}{2}(t^2-1)$$

Comment: Nice work today! TU!

Comment: I wish I could pull off late-nighters, even "all-nighters", like I used to in "my youth" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that Amzoti! Unfortunately still having some trouble with the integration step. If I integrate $\int{\frac{v'}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}dv}=\int{\frac{1}{t}dt}$ I do indeed get $\ln{t}+C$ on the RHS but on the LHS I get $\int{\sec^3{a}da}$ if I try and solve it with the substitution $v=\tan{a}$. What substitution should I be using? This one hasn't really gotten me very far... Thanks again!

Comment: @jamesh625: Okay, I added the details for the LHS of the integral and I assume you can do the RHS and then continue the simplifications, but give a yell if you get stuck. Regards

Comment: @jamesh625: Were you finally able to work this and converge on this and converge on the result?

Comment: @Amzoti: Thank you so much! I realised that I had multiplied by an extra $v'$ for some reason into my integral. Figured that out and it was easy work after the $x=tv$ substitution. :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @jamesh625: You are very welcome and glad it all worked out! Regards

Comment: @jamesh625: If you like answers and they are helpful, you should accept them, green arrow in order to not develop an rep for not doing that. Regards

Comment: Sorry to awaken an ancient thread! But I was just doing this exact problem and I was wondering, is this an example of a linear ODE?